# White pop-up when logged on google Drive (Google Drive SDK)

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm working on an app using google drive SDK. I am developping it with Javascript.

When I click on a button allowing me to open a view on my drive folder and I'm not logged in, a pop in propose me to log onto my google account. When I click on the connection button, a pop up appears and allow me to log in. When done, the pop up becomes white and don't close. The pop in with the connetion button also stays but in fact I am logged onto my account.
It is not user-friendly, I have to close the white pop up and close the connection pop in then to click on my button again to open a Google Drive folder pop in.

**I'd like the connection pop up to disapear when logged and the connection pop in to become a Google drive pop in.**

Comment: I doubt this request goes here as there is no programming question.

Comment: The thing is that this question is mostly destinated to Google Drive SDK developpers who could explain me what programming manipulation I should do to fix my problem or just tell me that it is developped this way and can't be change